# Anything similar to a parent view with sub-views in flex 4.6?

Tags: apache-flex, view, mxml, flex4.6

Is there any way to create a parent view with sub view system in flex?  For example I need to create an application that computes insurance rates for different products.  All products need to have the same inputs for gender, age, and nicotine usage.  What I'd like to do is have a 'parent view' (which wouldn't actually be displayed) that has all these basic fields layed out, then create sub views that automatically displays the components and layout of the parent view, which would cut back on duplicating code.  the sub views would have additional components unique to the product (some would also need to take in number of children, etc.) and compute the rates in different ways.

Edit: let's say I have 2 different products. ProdA and ProdB

This is the view for ProdA

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:components="spark.components.*" title="ProdA"
             xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[

        import ASClasses.LL;

        public function makeLL(age:String, gen:String, nic:String):void{
            var intAge:int=int(age);
            var newLL:LL=new LL(intAge, gen, nic);
            dest.text=String(newLL.computeRate());  
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center">

        <s:Label text="Age:"/>
        <s:TextInput id="age" restrict="0-9" maxChars="2"/>

        <s:ComboBox id="GenderBox" width="140" prompt="Gender" > 
            <s:dataProvider>
                <mx:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>Male</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Female</fx:String>
                </mx:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:ComboBox>

        <s:Label text="The selected gender is: {GenderBox.selectedItem}"/>

        <s:ComboBox id="NicotineBox" width="140" prompt="Nicotine Usage"> 
            <s:dataProvider>
                <mx:ArrayList>
                    <fx:String>Smoker</fx:String>
                    <fx:String>Non-Smoker</fx:String>
                </mx:ArrayList>
            </s:dataProvider>
        </s:ComboBox>

        <s:Label text="The selected Nicotine is: {NicotineBox.selectedItem}"/>

        <s:Button label="Get Rate" click="makeLL(age.text, GenderBox.selectedItem, NicotineBox.selectedItem)" />
        <s:TextInput id="dest" />       
    <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.popView()" styleName="back" />
</s:VGroup>
```

This is the view for ProdB

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<components:View xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" xmlns:components="spark.components.*" title="ProdB"
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx">
<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[
        import ASClasses.OP;

        public function makePerson(age:String, gen:String, nic:String):void{
            var intAge:int=int(age);
            var newOP:OP=new OP(intAge, gen, nic);
            dest.text=String(newOP.computeRate());  
        }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<s:VGroup width="100%" height="100%" verticalAlign="middle" horizontalAlign="center" >

    <s:Label text="Age:"/>
    <s:TextInput id="age" restrict="0-9" maxChars="2"/>

    <s:ComboBox id="GenderBox" width="140" prompt="Gender"> 
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Male</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Female</fx:String>
            </mx:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:ComboBox>

    <s:Label text="The selected gender is: {GenderBox.selectedItem}"/>

    <s:ComboBox id="NicotineBox" width="140" prompt="Nicotine Usage"> 
        <s:dataProvider>
            <mx:ArrayList>
                <fx:String>Smoker</fx:String>
                <fx:String>Non-Smoker</fx:String>
            </mx:ArrayList>
        </s:dataProvider>
    </s:ComboBox>

    <s:Label text="The selected Nicotine is: {NicotineBox.selectedItem}"/>

    <s:Button label="Get Rate" click="makePerson(age.text, GenderBox.selectedItem, NicotineBox.selectedItem)" />
    <s:TextInput id="dest" />       
    <s:Button label="Back" click="navigator.popView()" styleName="back" />
</s:VGroup>
```

Almost all the code is the same except for a few differences.  I'd like to have one view (Product) that contains all the duplicated code, then have ProdA and ProdB extend this product.  So that everything in the Product view shows up in both ProdA and ProdB

Comment: You mean like a spark List with an ItemRendererFunction?

Comment: I don't think so?  I added an edit that has a more in-depth example

Answer (score 1):

Use dependency injection (expose public properties that you can then bind to within the View), which frees you from having to define the whole thing inline as shown above.  it would look something like this

```
[Bindable]
public var dataProvider:ArrayList
//..other public vars
<s:ComboBox id="combo" width="140" prompt="{promptPublicVar}" >
          <s:dataProvider>{dataProviderPublicVar}</s:dataProvider>
          <s:change>publicVarContainingSelection=combo.selectedItem</s:change>
</s:ComboBox>  

<s:Label text="{label}: {publicVarContainingSelection}"/>
```

And you'd use it something like

```
<myNS:MyView>
   <myNS:prompt>Gender</myNS:prompt>
   <myNS:dataProvider><mx:ArrayList>...</mx:ArrayList></myNS:dataProvider>
   <myNS:label>The selected Gender is: </myNS:label>
</myNS:MyView>
```

===========not going to write any more code to try to guess what you want, so============

here are some patterns you might find useful:

- [Presentation Model](http://blogs.adobe.com/paulw/archives/2007/10/presentation_pa_3.html)
- [Abstract Classes](http://www.developria.com/2010/09/pragmatic-design-patterns-abst.html)
- [Template  Components](http://www.developria.com/2010/05/code-behind-vs-template-compon.html)

Note that the third link also mentions Code behind, which can be used as a type of abstract class.

Also, you might want to consider [composition over inheritance](http://www.developria.com/2010/09/pragmatic-design-patterns-comp.html). For example, your view shouldn't know or care how to calculate rate information, but could have a rate calculator data component passed to it.  Which it most emphatically [should not](http://misko.hevery.com/2008/09/30/to-new-or-not-to-new/) be creating for itself--this is one of the reasons you're having such a hard time arriving at a reusable design.

Comment: I re-edited the post to show both views to hopeufully give you a better idea of what I'm trying to accomplish.  Thanks for the time you're putting into this, I appreciate it.